# Navigation bar button action fails to call

Tags: ios, uinavigationcontroller, uinavigationbar, uibarbuttonitem, uinavigationitem

I am using following code to show `DashBoardContainerVC` in app delegate:

```
UIStoryboard *storyboard = self.window.rootViewController.storyboard;
        UINavigationController *svc = [storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"DashBoardNavigationController"];
        self.window.rootViewController = svc;
```

Code for navigation bar button is:

```
self.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem = [self leftMenuBarButtonItem];

- (UIBarButtonItem *)leftMenuBarButtonItem {
    return [[UIBarButtonItem alloc]
            initWithImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"menu-icon"] style:UIBarButtonItemStylePlain
            target:self
            action:@selector(menuButton:)];
}
```

`menuButton` action fails to call in this case. But when i am using the code like the one below, it works fine:

```
UIStoryboard *storyboard = self.window.rootViewController.storyboard;
        DashBoardContainerVC *svc = [storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:NSStringFromClass([DashBoardContainerVC class])];
        UINavigationController *nav = [[UINavigationController alloc]initWithRootViewController:svc];
        self.window.rootViewController = nav;
```

So what's issue in my first code. Any suggestions.?

Comment: Add the iOS tag to this question - you are likely to reach a larger audience.

Comment: Have you checked that svc is not null in your first example?

Comment: No its not nil. i have verified it again. Navigation bar button ("menu-icon" image) is displaying but its action is not working.

Answer (score 0):

I had same issue with storyboard, Your code has no issue, There is some bug with storyboard, Just delete your view/scene form storyboard and add them again.